# How to do nested if statements in Librecalc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Are nested `if` statements supported in Librecalc?

According to [this article](https://exceljet.net/formula/nested-if-function-example) about Excel, `if` statements should be nestable.

However, if I enter this formula into a Librecalc spreasheet:

```
=If(1>2, "a", If(2>1, "b", "c"))
```

Instead of displaying "b", it fails to evaluate the second `if` statment at all and renders it as straight text `If(2>1, "b", "c")`.

Why is this?

Comment: Are you trying to create something like the [IFS function](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_ifs.html)?

Comment: The [correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3rAl.png) is returned on my side.

Comment: Try copying and pasting the following into your sheet: `=IF(1>2; "a"; IF(2>1; "b"; "c"))`. Another thing to check—are you using different formula names instead of English? Your question shows the case as "If" when it should be automatically capitalized by Calc to "IF", perhaps indicating that it is not recognized as a formula. Be sure that there is no `'` before the formula.